# JavaScript Cell with same values as others is represented as null

Tags: javascript

I looked up if similar questions were already asked did not get a good answer. I have cells that have that outer HTML

```
<div class="cell cellSymbol" id="cell" data-x="2" data-y="8" style="width: calc((100% / 9) - 0.5 * var(--shadowsize)); height: calc((100% / 9) - 0.5 * var(--shadowsize));"></div>
```

which is accessible and another like that

```
<div class="cell" id="cell" data-x="3" data-y="8" style="width: calc((100% / 9) - 0.5 * var(--shadowsize)); height: calc((100% / 9) - 0.5 * var(--shadowsize));"></div>
```

which´s values are not accessible. Since they are totally the same besides having different classes I do not understand why my query selector says the second one is null and the first one is not.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cell is null

is the error message if I click the null cell.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add your JavaScript that sets the `cell` variable.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Element is null` either means that the element does not exist or the script is executed before the script knows this element. Also possibly caused because you assigned the id `cell` multiple times. An id has to be unique! Last but not least, the "only" way to select multiple elements is either `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` which returns array-like objects (Node List or HTML Collection Object).

Comment: two elements cannot have the same id.

Comment: do you put your script tag at the bottom or at the top?